Calculating median value
I have a text file containing thousands of lines, a single numeric value on each line. Values are between -2.5 - 2.5, single decimal.
I am using this line to give me the lowest value, highest value, median and average value.
awk '{a[i++]=$0;s+=$0}END{print a[0],a[i-1],(a[int(i/2)]+a[int((i-1)/2)])/2,s/i}

It's otherwise perfect, but I'd like to get the median as a decimal number with one decimal. It now returns an integer.
Can you help me?
My knowledge of awk is very limited. Perhaps someone more educated can help me.

please update the question with a sample input file (10 lines should be sufficient), the current output of your script against the sample input file, and the expected output; having said that ... have you considered replacing print with printf? alternatively you could wrap the item in question in a sprintf() function call

What do you mean by "a decimal number with one decimal."?  .3 instead of the 0 integer?  If that is the case, what is "between -2.5 - 2.5, single decimal"?   It looks like you are well on your way (assuming the list is sorted--is it?), awk should be able to do this despite its limits (but there are a few other issues).

You probably want to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in (i.e. don't a hammer when you can use a calculator =)

Sorry for disturbing you.
By using your hints, I found out that the decimal in median is NOT printed if it is ZERO.
pi@iittipi3:/var/tmpram $ cat file
-0.8
-0.3
-0.2
-0.2
-0.2
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.1
-0.0
-0.0
0.1
0.1
0.3
1.0
1.8
pi@iittipi3:/var/tmpram $ cat file | awk '{a[i++]=$0;s+=$0}END{print a[0],a[i-1],(a[int(i/2)]+a[int((i-1)/2)])/2,s/i}'
-0.8 1.8 -0.1 0.0647059
pi@iittipi3:/var/tmpram $
...but it is printed if non-zero.

update the question with these additional details; do not bury them in comments

I'm not sure what you mean by "a decimal number with one decimal" (I could not get 0.1 to be .1, if that's what you wanted), and you'll need to ensure your version of awk supports asort(), but this (run today at https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-awk-online, which should be "NU AWK 5.1.1, with an API version of 3.1" as far as I can tell) should help:
Code:
BEGIN{
    highest=-2.6
    lowest=2.6
}{
    a[NR]=$0
    if($0>highest){highest=$0}
    if($0<lowest){lowest=$0}
    average=average+$0
}END{
    n=asort(a)
    if(n%2==1){median=a[(n+1)/2]}else{median=(a[n/2]+a[n/2+1])/2}
    printf("lowest=%f, highest=%f, average=%f, median=%1.1f\n",
    lowest, highest, average/NR, median)
}

Input (Note-- It cannot have a blank line.):
-2.5
-1.4
0.1
-0.9
2.4
2.3
2.2

Output:
lowest=-2.500000, highest=2.400000, average=0.314286, median=0.1


I figured out how to force 0.1 to be printed as .1, but I'm not sure if that means 0.14 should be .1, if .16 should be .1 or .2, if 1.1 should be 1, etc.  Currently, it prints 2 decimal digits and rounds, ties round down.
